# Firebase Unauthorized access

Tags: html, css, firebase, firebase-authentication

Consider the following web application flow.

1. user hits login/sign up page
2. user signs up and logs in
3. browser redirects to their profile page

My question is, using firebase authentication services, how do I restrict usage of the profile page without authorization to the web application?

Moreover, can I host this web application on firebase, and this functionality will be taken care of for me?

Answer (score 1):

Well profile pages for example are generally sites that are dynamically filled with data. You don't have to restrict access to the page itself but instead restrict the API with the JSON restrictions settings firebase offers. This way nobody can access any other profile pages than their own. To prevent annoying users which have for example saved a link to their profile page but are not logged in you can add a redirect users that are not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a new project using firebase console and deploy your application to it. You can also enable email authentication to the application on firebase. Follow this link for more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup